# DEBUG macro is not set in Xcode while running the project in debug mode

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

I created a new react-native project which spits out an Android project and an iOS project. I am using Swift, so I replace the `AppDelegate.m` and `AppDelegate.h` files with `AppDelegate.swift`. I use the `DEBUG` macro like this in the swift file but it is always set to false even in debug mode due to which I am not able to use it.

```swift
    #if DEBUG
      let jsCodeLocation = RCTBundleURLProvider.sharedSettings().jsBundleURL(forBundleRoot: "index", fallbackResource:nil)
    #else
      let jsCodeLocation = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "main", withExtension: "jsbundle")
    #endif
```

I searched for `debug` in `Build Settings` on Xcode and I found the below which seems to be set correctly.

[image]

How can I assure that the `DEBUG` macro is set while running the debug mode and not set otherwise. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Open your Project Build Settings and search for `Swift Compiler – Custom Flags`
2. And under this go to `Other Swift Flags` and add `-DDEBUG` to the Debug section

Let me know if this works, I used this approach for my [lib](https://github.com/InderKumarRathore/MLog) long time back

Comment: This worked for me, but I want to know the reason for the issue. I have another projects working without these configurations,